# How can i found only the less count values Name Must want 3 groupName also

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

IN SQL (adventureWorks) Database...

```
I/P :
ALTER PROCEDURE spLessDep
AS
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(Name) AS COUNT,max(GroupName)
FROM HumanResources.Department
WHERE GroupName <(SELECT MAX(GroupName) FROM HumanResources.Department)
GROUP BY GroupName
ORDER BY COUNT(Name)
END

EXEC spLessDep
```

O/P:

```
Name   GroupName

2      Inventory Management
2      Manufacturing
2      Quality Assurance
3      Research and Development
5      Executive General and Administration
```

Require: I want all minimum values in column(name) by the only statement

Comment: What is your question here? What isn't working about your attempt? Is it the missing batch separator?

Comment: Your question is how to use the `Advertureworks2019` database? That's far too broad a question for [so].

Comment: USE [AdventureWorks2019] ---- Tablename is HumanResource.Department--- i want get all  least count of values in Name(column) Based by GroupName(column) ---- dont numeric values on query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are describing `TOP (1) WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES COUNT(Name) AS COUNT, GroupName
FROM HumanResources.Department
WHERE GroupName < (SELECT MAX(GroupName) FROM HumanResources.Department)
GROUP BY GroupName
ORDER BY COUNT(Name);
```